# spring application does not use embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications, pom.xml

The spring application won't run as web application and does not use the embedded tomcat server. I have provided my console and pom.xml logs. Please help me.

```
2017-03-17 01:38:09.426  INFO 18696 --- [           main] io.springbootstarter.SpringCourseApi     : Starting SpringCourseApi on gandy with PID 18696 (C:\Spring\workspace\course-api\target\classes started by gandhar in C:\Spring\workspace\course-api)
2017-03-17 01:38:09.431  INFO 18696 --- [           main] io.springbootstarter.SpringCourseApi     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-17 01:38:09.539  INFO 18696 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5ae50ce6: startup date [Fri Mar 17 01:38:09 MDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-17 01:38:11.361  INFO 18696 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-17 01:38:11.383  INFO 18696 --- [           main] io.springbootstarter.SpringCourseApi     : Started SpringCourseApi in 2.662 seconds (JVM running for 3.22)
2017-03-17 01:38:11.384  INFO 18696 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5ae50ce6: startup date [Fri Mar 17 01:38:09 MDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-17 01:38:11.385  INFO 18696 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

This is my console output when i try to run a web application. My pom.xml looks like this -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springboot.courses</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Course_API</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


</project>
```

Comment: try to refresh your maven dependencies.

Comment: how do you do that ? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: when you build application terminal - `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Does not help my case. I tried it several times.

Comment: I am trying to run it in STS which already has inbuilt maven. i manually deleted maven dependencies from .m2 folder and still does not work. Any other workaround ?

Comment: maybe try exclude tomcat dependency from `spring-boot-starter-web` and add dependency `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` or you can configure embeded `jetty`

Comment: got it to work !! Thanks !!